# Accessing images in javascript in rails 3.2

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, assets

I have view *diplay.html.erb* corresponding to action display in *locations* controller.

I am using application.js in assets/javascript folder.

I am using javascript function of *application.js* in the *display.html.erb* file.

In this function I am loading image but the image is not loaded when used path:

such as `"car.png"` or `"\images\car.png"` 
 but when used path
`"http://localhost:3000/assets/car.png"` it is displayed properly.

so what path should I give in *application.js* to access image in /assets/images folder?

Comment: I don't want to give 'http://localhost:3000' in a path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no confusion, 
you need to use `http://localhost:3000/assets/car.png` to see image 
if car.png is located at assets/images/car.png -that's rails convention.

I found the answer:

using `<img src="/assets/car.png" />` when car.png in `assets/images/car.png`

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be confused with your own folder structure. If the image is located under /assets/car.png then you should probably use 'assets' instead of 'images' in your path. Doesn't this work?

```
<img src="/assets/car.png" />
```

But if the image is under /assets/images/car.png then it would rather be:

```
<img src="/assets/images/car.png" />
```